# Get ThinkPad orientation

Tags: screen, thinkpad, sensors

On Windows, screen orientation of my ThinkPad W520 can automatically change if I rotate the computer to hold it like a book. Is it possible to detect computer orientation on Linux?

Answer (score 3):

I finally found the solution. The driver for the accelerometer of the ThinkPad is in package `tp-smapi-dkms`. Then I must load the `hdaps` module. The position can now be accessed in `/sys/devices/platform/hdaps/position`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it can rotate automatically, but you can always change your orientation by editing it in your display settings. Just type display in the dash and click in dislay icon