# ACPI or other event for (physical) screen rotation on ThinkPad X220

Tags: lenovo, hardware

I have a ThinkPad X220 where one can flip the screen. I'd like to use the physical state of the laptop in a script, like letting ACPI or udev call the rotation script when I rotate the laptop.

How can I find out where the state of the laptop is exposed, if at all?

The states that I mean:

[image] 
[image]

Comment: Just to check - is this possible on other OSs?

Comment: Never booted Windows on this one, so I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

[I found this on the thinkpads forum](http://forum.thinkpads.com/viewtopic.php?p=676101). Relevant part of the script in the link:

```
rotation="$(xrandr -q --verbose | grep 'connected' | egrep -o  '\) 
(normal|left|inverted|right) \(' | egrep -o '(normal|left|inverted|right)')"
```

Comment: My [think-rotate](http://martin-ueding.de/projects/think-rotate) is based on this. But that only queries the current rotation state of the screen. It has nothing to do with the *physical* state of the screen.

Comment: Ok true, then please explain to me what you mean with "physical state". To me the physical state of the screen changes when -I- walk around the table (since the screen from my point of view turned up side down).

Comment: I added some images.

Comment: He's looking for something that polls a sensor as opposed to the existent state.

Answer (score -1):

https://askubuntu.com/a/349239

and

https://askubuntu.com/a/611062

combined with

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LaptopLidAndDockScripts

might help you find a solution. Currently looking into the same issue. Will post again if I arrive at a script solution artifact in sensible amounts of time.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1207636)